# Custom Meta Field Has Stopped Working

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom meta checkbox in a custom post type that until this afternoon was working fine, I went into add some new post types and the checkbox won't save I did add the isset value in the show_meta but it was still working after I did this and does not start working again if I remove it, and nothing is showing up in my debug can anybody help?:

```
    function add_tiles_meta_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'tiles_meta_box', // $id
    'Show in Large Tiles?', // $title
    'show_tiles_meta_box', // $callback
    'tiles', // $screen
    'normal', // $context
    'high' // $priority
);
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_tiles_meta_box' );
function show_tiles_meta_box( $post, $metabox ) {
$tiles = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tiles', true ); 

wp_nonce_field( basename(__FILE__), 'tiles_meta_box_nonce' );
?>

<!-- All fields will go here -->
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tiles"  <?php echo (isset($_POST['tiles'])?"value='on'":"value='off'")?> <?php checked( $tiles, 'on' ); ?>/>  Yes this is a large tile.
</p>

<?php
}
$post_ID = $post->ID;

function save_tiles_meta($post_ID) {
$post_ID = (int) $post_ID;
$post_type = get_post_type($post_ID);
$post_status = get_post_status( $post_ID );

if ($post_type) {
update_post_meta($post_ID, "tiles", $_POST["tiles"]);
}
     return $post_ID;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_tiles_meta' );
```

Comment: Can you tell me one this why you have declared $post_id before the function(save_tiles_meta()) ? Can you just remove that?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was there, I have removed it now. Doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Your `save_tiles_meta` function is unnecessarily convoluted. Something may be failing along the way. Here's a more standard way to do that:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_tiles_meta' );
function save_tiles_meta(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tiles', $_POST['tiles'] ); // On or Off
}
```

Comment: I have altered the save_tiles_meta to match but it hasn't resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_tiles_meta',99,1 );
function save_tiles_meta($postId){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tiles', $_POST['tiles'] ); // On or Off
}
```